# Can Elasticsearch filter by a date range without specifying a field?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I have multiple date fields and I want to have a single date range query to filter by *any* of them.

For example, I may have books in my index, and each book may have a *published date*, *edition date*, *print date*, and the *author's birth date*.

The mapping is straightforward (generated using [Elasticsearch.net Nest](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net)):

```
"printDate" : {
    "type" : "date",
    "format" : "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
},
```

I looked at [range queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html) and [query string ranges](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_ranges) - both need the name of the field explicitly and don't seem to support wildcards.
For example, this doesn't find anything, but works if I use a real field name instead of `"*Date"`:

```
"filter": [
  {
    "range": {
      "*Date": {
        "gte": "2010-01-01T00:00:00",
        "lte": "2015-01-01T00:00:00"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I also tried placing `[2010-01-01 TO 2015-01-01]` in a query string, but the dates aren't parsed correctly - it also finds `2010` or `01` as part of other strings (and seemingly other dates).
Another option is to list each field under a `"should"` clause and specifying `"minimum_should_match":1`, but that will make me maintain a list of all date fields, which seems inelegant.

Is there a way of searching for a date range on all date fields?

Comment: I would go with `query_string` that does support wildcard field names.

Comment: Also, ES will not magically pick the fields that are only of type `date` for example. You need to help it a bit. By using similar names for the date fields and then using wildcards for field names and so on.

Comment: @AndreiStefan - I tried query string and wildcards, but it doesn't parse the dates as such, it looks for strings instead.

Comment: Ok. Can you share the query that you tried and which fails? Also, please provide the mappings for those fields used in the query.

Comment: @AndreiStefan - Sure, here it is. It's possible this is just not supported, of course. If `*Date` would work it would have solved my problem - only and all these fields end with `Date`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "*Date", 
      "query": "[2010-01-01T00:00:00 TO 2015-01-01T00:00:00]"
    }
  }
}
```